# Filter Parse.Object properties that should get saved to the server

Tags: parse-platform

I have this Parse.Object that I want to save to the server, but I'd like to whitelist the attributes of this object that get saved.

```
Parse.Object.extend('someObject', {
  defaults: {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,

    computedProperty: function() {
      return this.get('foo') + this.get('bar')
    }
  },

  get: function(attr) {
    var value = Parse.Object.prototype.get.call(this, attr)

    return _.isFunction(value) ? value.call(this) : value
  }
})
```

As you can see, this object has a [computed property](http://kilon.org/blog/2012/02/backbone-calculated-fields/) among its attributes. I would like to filter out the computedProperty when I save this Parse.Object. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

So, we've figured out a way to filter the list of attributes that get saved.

If you wanna do it, you have to override a private, undocumented method on the Parse.Object called `_getSaveJSON`, so the complete model above would be:

```
Parse.Object.extend('someObject', {
  defaults: {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,

    computedProperty: function() {
      return 1+2
    }
  },

  get: function(attr) {
    var value = Parse.Object.prototype.get.call(this, attr)

    return _.isFunction(value) ? value.call(this) : value
  },

  _getSaveJSON: function() {
    var model = this
    var json = _.clone(_.first(this._opSetQueue))
    Parse._objectEach(json, function(op, key) {
      json[key] = op.toJSON();
    });
    var whitelistedAttributes = ['foo', 'bar']

    return _.pick(json, whitelistedAttributes)
  }
})
```